# How to get jQuery to erase and/or append a value to the end of a URL variable?

Tags: jquery, string, url

<strike>Well, I'll start out with the current project (of sorts). I'm currently designing a custom Tumblr theme for myself. Within the theme, I have included a script where when a trigger button is clicked, a form appears. The intended function of the form is for a user to willingly enter a numerical value that when submitted, will redirect the current page to the specified one.</strike>

<strike>The HTML markup is as follows:</strike>

```
<form id="jump">
    <input name="page" value="{CurrentPage}" />
    <span class="total">of {TotalPages}:</span>
    <input type="submit" id="go" value="Go" />
</form>
```

> <strike><sub>**Note: {CurrentPage} outputs to the current page number (i.e. - 1) and {TotalPages} outputs to the total number of pages (i.e. - 3). So, "{CurrentPage} of {TotalPages}" could easily be inferred as "1 of 3".*</sub></strike>

<strike>Now, this is where I get stumped. I currently have this script in my current theme because I've utilized this form before:</strike>

```
$(function() {
    $('#jump').submit(function() {
        document.location = 'http://user.tumblr.com/page/' + parseInt($('input[name=page]').val());
    });
});
```

<strike>This actually worked. However, the problem that I discovered is that it really only works on index pages (such as *http://user.tumblr.com/* or *http://user.tumblr.com/page/2*).</strike>

<strike>If the URL were to be something like *http://user.tumblr.com/tagged/words/page/2* (or let alone *http://user.tumbr.com/tagged/words*), the script only redirects to the index type pages (*http://user.tumblr.com/page/3*).</strike>

<strike>So, I figured why not store the current URL in a variable and try to append the value somehow?  Consequently, the script appends a query string to the URL and the result is something like *http://user.tumblr.com/tagged/words?page=1*. Or, if it's a page URL (with */page/2* at the end), it erases that part of the value and changes it to the query string. And that's not it; it seems that you can actually exceed the total amount of pages (meaning I could jump to a page 4 if there's only three pages, which in any case can be displayed as a 404 or "no results found" page).</strike>

<strike>This brings me to my desperate plea for help. I figured that I could modify the jQuery to retrieve the current page URL, erase the number following the */page/* part of the string , and then append the new value at the end. On the other hand, if the current page URL is the index page (*http://user.tumblr.com/* or even *http://user.tumblr.com/tagged/words), I would like to append */page/* and then the numerical value afterward. It'd be neat to also somehow be able to get the number of total pages and enforce it as a limitation to which page a user can skip to (which would disallow a user to go page 4/5/6/etc. if there's only three pages).</strike>

<strike>I don't really have a clue how it can be done. I've tried using a few methods (like **.substring();**, **lastIndexOf();**, etc.). I also have a feeling I could use PHP to do this (and just define the action in the HTML form markup), but alas, I'm clueless on how to do it there as well. I think it'd be a lot easier, though, but I can't exactly decide which to use. Although, it'd be cool to know how to do it in both, for future reference but it's not entirely mandatory at the moment.</strike>

<strike>My apologies for the tedious essay, but I suppose I should end it with the universal question that benefits both parties... Help?</strike>

---

## Edit

I've come to the conclusion that my perfectionist attitude was just adding to frustration I didn't need. Hence, I'm no longer in need of assistance. I went ahead and made the page jumping function primarily available for the index pages (any pages without extra directories such as */tagged* or */search*). For the other pages, I merely used Tumblr's API to hide the form, rendering it useless at that point. Besides, it really isn't that big of a deal, it's only meant to be a small little extra within my theme.

Thanks to those who answered, though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to brush up on your JavaScript.  I fear many people get sucked into jQuery and do not realize there is a whole world of JavaScript that jQuery does not expose.

here's my stab at it:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#jump').submit(function ()
    {
        var page = parseInt($('input[name=page]').val());
        var total = parseInt($('input[name=total]').val())
        if (page > total)
        {
            page = total;
        }
        document.location = 'http://user.tumblr.com/page/' + page;
    });
});
```

The above will require the following hidden field added as a shortcut to get the total page count:

```
<input name="page" type="hidden" value="{TotalPages}" />
```

This doesn't solve ALL of your issues, but it's what I have so far... I may tackle the URL problems after I answer some emails.

Comment: It works... to its extent. But, I actually had already implemented the page to total values in the script before you had posted. Thanks, though. As comment earlier, I've chosen to make this more simple. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's two primary problems you're trying to solve:

1. Smart handling of URLs that may already have a `/page/#` part of the URL.
2. Prevent skipping to a page that does not exist.

I believe this should take care of both problems:

```
$(function() {
    $('#jump').submit(function() {
        var maxPage = parseInt($('#_total_pages').val(), 10),
            newPage;

        // strip page number from URL
        curPage = curPage.replace(/\/page\/\d+\/?/, '');
        curPage = curPage.replace(/\?page=\d+?/, '');

        // check page number
        newPage = parseInt($('input[name=page]').val(), 10);
        if (newPage < 1 || newPage > maxPage) {
            // bad page
            alert('Invalid page number: ' + newPage);
            return;
        }

        // append page number to URL
        if (/\?/.test(curPage)) {
            curPage += '&page=' newPage;
        } else {
            curPage += '/page/' + newPage;
        }
        window.location = curPage;
    });
});
```

You will need to add this HTML to track the total number of pages.

```
<input id="_total_pages" type="hidden" value="{TotalPages}" />
```

This solution should handle any input URL and also check the max number of pages.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It's okay, though. I've decided to ditch this nonsense and utilize it in a more simple fashion.